# toolStrip and statusStrip location

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, toolstrip, statusstrip

How I can achieve something like this?

[image]

I tried to set toolstrip dock to left

[image]

toolstrip dock to none

[image]

statusstrip dock to none

[image]

Comment: What if you dock again the status strip to the bottom? Maybe it'll snap as you want. Order can matter.

Comment: that's in the second picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Z-order issue.  Right click on the control and try "Bring to Front" or "Send to Back". You may also have to click on your other docked controls and change their z-order as well.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Form1.Designer.cs (From1 is the name of your form) designer generated file. Go to the section where the strips are added to the Controls collection of the form, and switch the order, like so:

```
this.Controls.Add(this.toolStrip1);
this.Controls.Add(this.statusStrip1);
```

This way the status trip will be in the right Z order (in terms of layouting too).